# Is Devise worth using as of 2017?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

There are so many bugs and headaches especially when customizing user authentication. I could easily use has_secure_password and be done with it. Is Devise really better than lets say Michael Hartl's has_secure_password way?

Comment: You compare apples with pears. `has_secure_password` just hashes a password and allows to authenticate against that password. `devise` does way more than that: email verification, password recovery, session handing, logging of user  actions and more.

Comment: If you have a lot of customizations, you may be better off rolling your own. Its going to take some time, but probably not much more than what you will spend in making devise act as you want.

Answer (score 0):

The only applications I can imagine Devise is not worth it are the ones with a very specific user authentication system or the ones that require nothing more than what the `has_secure_password` approach does.

When I say "a very specific user authentication system" I mean a set of specific conditions that devise is not built for, which have been quite rare to me so far. You haven't mentioned what customizations are a headache so one may not be totally sure of what you mean.

Devise has quite a few methods that can be overriden to easily customize its behavior, so it surely handles most requirements of the current applications.

If you want the vague answer: Using Devise is always worth it if it can handle your project requirements, and it usually can, even in 2017.

If you want the specific answer: Well, you could be more specific too.